# Sync session token in Joomla

Tags: session, joomla, single-sign-on, session-cookies, access-token

**CMS**- Joomla! 2.5
**Task**- When i login to www.domain.com(A), i should be automatically be logged into test.domain.com(B) and vice-versa.
**Implementation**
When i visit site A, a session cookie is set to have the session id. Once i login to site A, the user credentials are checked and then the session record in j25_session table is updated with user id. Once this is done, i can freely navigate through the site A, as the session id is on the session cookie.
The cookie id and the session id stored in the cookie is the same on site B. This is because i have set the cookie domain on both websites as .domain.com and i am using the same secret value in the configuration file. Also Site B has access to the session data of site A, as the tables are being shared(created views).
So ideally even if i move from site A to B, the session should be valid and i should be logged in.
**Issue**
The session becomes invalid when i move from site A to B. As far as i've investigated, this is due to the token that is in the login form. the token in the form and the token saved in the session differs, this makes the session to die.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems you would need to face if you want do do this manually.
First of all there's a great component - **JFusion** with good support but I'm not sure if it allows bi-directional sessions between two joomla sites. Check it out, you could save many hours if not days!

### Users

In order to authenticate someone an a different joomla site there must by the same database record in both #__users table on site A and site B, with the same IDs and usernames in addition to the same session cookie.

A few ways to solve this:

- create a **user** plugin which synchronizes entries in #_*users and #*_user_usergroup_map from site A to B and vice versa. This must handle creating data after registration, removing records after deletion and updating it.
- use MySQL replication (Master <-> Master) to synchronize #_*users and #*_user_usergroup_map tables between site A and B and vice versa

### Sharing sessions

In order to share a valid session between 2 Joomla webites both need to have access to the same session cookie and #__sessions table, which you already implemented from what I understand, right?

If not, this is the biggest issue you have to face. A few ways to solve it:

- use curl to get login form of the site B
- use regular expressions to pull out the token from
- send a POST request to the component users with login task on site B

the other is:

- assuming #__users table is the same on both sides
- after successful authentication on site A create the same session record in table #__sessions on site B

another, and the best solution:

- use MySQL replication (Master <-> Master) to replicate #__sessions table between both sites

### Sessions expiration

Even when you implement shared sessions you may need to face this issue. Sessions on site A and B will have different expiration time. That means when you login on site A the session on site B may expire earlier so that you won't be logged in on site B when you visit it.

You could solve it by:

- setting up the same "Session expires after" setting in Joomla backend on both sites.
- replicating #__users table either with MySQL replication or **users** plugins on both sites.

There's lot of work to achieve this, but even if you decided to do it manually check out a few extensions just to see how they do it.
Good luck

### EDIT: I also recommend checking out this extensions:

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/19249
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/7557
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/5550
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/multiple-sites/14863